# How much of an effect do deleted questions have on bans?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban

I have done some reading and learned that good answers can get you out of a question ban, so hopefully I won't be blocked for too long, but how big of an impact do deleted questions have? I have one question whose score is -6 that I am **really** considering deleting, but want to make sure that such an action wouldn't cause too much harm.

Comment: Single instances of deleted questions don't do any harm. Ideally, you'll improve your bad answers and they'll get upvoted, but in the real world... an old answer doesn't really get looked at ever again. The various posting bans are for people who Just Don't Get It and repeatedly post junk. If you're not doing this, you don't have anything to worry about.

Comment: Also note that you have two answers currently at -2, you may want to try and improve those.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Umm.. I don't know what you're referring to. I have 1 answer with -2 which I deleted when I realized I misinterpretted the question completely, but I didn't see another one....

Comment: This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162282/whatt-there-at-address-0-usually/28162345#28162345 and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869346/merge-two-integers-as-integer-decimal-in-c/27869436#27869436

Comment: @AndréDaniel Weird I didm't see either... ty for pointing that out, but I think the downvotes were more "He didn't ask for that, and I don't like that answer" rather than "This answer is of low quality / presents wrong information". Nonetheless, I'll see if I can do anything.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not much.

Unless, y'know, that's *all you have*. I mean, if you signed onto the site and everything you post gets deleted, it'd be pretty stupid for the system to let you keep posting. So, folks who start off posting nothing but spam or non-answers or trolling or confused nonsense... They tend to hit the ban really fast.

Of course, the bigger problem with deleted questions is that if there are other problems then they don't stop counting *against you*. If you have a question scoring -6, it's still a question you wrote that scores -6 after you delete it. As far as the system is concerned, you're the same person you were before. It ain't gonna get any *worse*, but... It won't get better either.

Finally, it's worth noting a particular case where deleting questions counts *heavily* toward a question ban: deleting them right after someone posts an answer. Believe it or not, some folks make a *habit* of doing this, and... it's generally seen as abusive, particularly by the folks answering. So, y'know, don't do *that.*

---

Aside: usually the best way to get out of a question-ban isn't to worry about your *worst* questions - it's to make the ones that are already ok look great, and the ones that are good even better. A question that was understood and got a good answer is a question that others are likely to find useful - *if* they can find it. So make the titles descriptive, make sure they have the right tags, and clean up any little formatting or writing issues.

Comment: I understand how it's abusive when user deletes their own answered question, that makes perfect sense. What I don't understand though is whether this also applies in case when answers are deleted by system at migration (this was discussed at Progs meta, user hit block _solely_ for migrated answered questions). I asked to clarify this at MSE: [For quality blocks / warnings, system seems to penalize migrated answered questions the same as deleted ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240660/165773)

Comment: Irrelevant unless mod-deleted; counts as a closed question.

Comment: does [automatic Community♦ cleanup](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/256140/revisions "as in this example") count as "mod deletion" for q-block algorithm? I ask because this seems what happened in [case I refered to in prior comment](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6909/why-did-i-receive-a-question-quality-warning#comment18693_6909)

Comment: No. Note that the case you're referencing involved a *warning*, not a *ban* - the closure itself would've been sufficient to trigger that.

Comment: great to hear that thanks! I understand the difference between warning and ban, I was only worried that warning looked like triggered a bit too eagerly (two questions in more than a month - [1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/252908/31260), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/256140/31260) - both migrated with 0/0 score). It was really rare case when I could understand warned asker's complain in another comment over there: "I know better than to argue with a cabal making secret rules"

Comment: @gnat How does it make sense? Someone spent time answering the question, and the moment you got your solution you just nuked their content and prevented anyone else from benefiting from it? That's just not what SO is for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think you've misinterpreted gnat's comment, but one scenario I ran into myself (on another SE site) is that an answer that completely misses the point of the question, particularly following on from comments that similarly miss the point, can be the last straw.  It made it obvious to me that I just wasn't going to get a sensible answer, at which point I deleted the question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That can happen. I wonder whether the mechanism Shog relates to kicks in if the answer has a negative score.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in migration, one can't tell that content is really nuked - it is moved to other SE site and link at "source" site even redirects to where it is moved. It's more complicated than straightforward deletion

Comment: @gnat Yeah I didn't even touch on migration. Don't know about it. I was responding to your initial statement, about something making "perfect sense" that on inspection seems not to!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ah that. I guess my wording was unclear. I meant to say that deleting answered questions looks 200%  abusive to me, and I understand why system punishes that

Comment: @gnat: Apparently I read a "not" in there that didn't exist. :P Apologies