# Why was I banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, post-ban

Why was I banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow?

I understand that many of my questions mostly have 0 up votes, but that is mainly because they are very specialized towards what I do, and are not too useful to most people. I don't understand how I qualified for a ban.

Comment: Have you deleted any of your previous questions? I'm 99% confident the system wouldn't impose a ban for what I can see on your profile.

Comment: I deleted a question many years ago. Other than that, no. (As far as I can remember)

Comment: Hmm Take a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. Do you think your questions match that criteria? I am taking a look at your iOS related questions right now

Comment: I think so, although one is not a very good judge of his own work. Most of them were many years ago, so would the system still judge them?

Comment: From Help Center: "[...]users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts." That seems rather unfair, doesn't it? Just because your questions don't help others doesn't mean that they are poorly written, or anything like that. *sigh* stereotypes

Comment: On stackoverflow, we try to keep things in a way that it can help not only the OP but countless other programmers in the future. We all have benefited from this policy :) Just googling the keywords returns the solution from stackoverflow.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Based on seeing dozens if not hundreds of these sorts of plaintive questions before, I am 95% certain you've forgotten at least two or three more deleted, downvoted/closed questions.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Fine. In order to dis/prove that, how can I look at my deleted questions? I see no way to do it in my profile... (Would I ask a moderator? How?) Thank you!

Comment: You'd have to ask a mod, yes. One might show up here, or you could try chat.

Comment: Which chat channel? (I do not use chat)

Comment: Whenever I have a question regarding mod policies (For reviews), I pop by [SO close vote review chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: This is a question that can only be answered by a moderator. It is a valid question for meta, and not all that bad. For all we know, there could be a glitch in the system that caused a user to be banned without reason, even though it is far more likely that they have some deleted questions contributing to the ban. It will require an explanation from a moderator, but is not off-topic.

Comment: Do you have some deleted, downvoted questions? The downvoted questions would likely be contributing to the ban.  You can search for them with `user:me deleted:1`.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  The fact that the question is deleted by itself [doesn't apply to the ban all that much](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287903/1079354).  If they're *downvoted*, or someone answered the question which was *then* deleted that would very much apply.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that, but didn't say it. Thanks @Makoto. I just don't understand why it is being downvoted so harshly. The guy is honestly trying to figure out why he is banned.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  I can sympathize somewhat, but in most of the cases I've seen of this scenario, the situation is rarely one that we mere mortals can answer directly.  Information about the situation is missing, since we can see that there isn't all that much to trigger a question ban, but there are things that only moderators know and could answer that would be able to supply an answer.  Deleted and downvoted questions are one of those things.

Comment: Yeah, and as I said in my first comment here, it *is* a question that can only be answered by a moderator, but it is still on-topic here. As it is tagged support, at some point a moderator will come along and hopefully impart upon the user the knowledge necessary to understand the conditions behind their ban. I *still* don't understand why it is being downvoted like it is. @Makoto

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've asked 10 questions in total. Two of them have seen a positive reception. Three of them were received quite negatively, and were deleted some time ago now.

The rest, all answered, all score 0.

So the system looks at this & decides there's probably not a great chance that you'll ask a positively-received question. After all, out of the three possible outcomes, that one has been the most rare in your past history...

The fastest way to change this is to get some positive attention to those 5 questions that currently sit at 0. [Get this one reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037077/how-do-you-code-a-button-that-on-press-will-print-out-the-entire-viewcontrolle), [elaborate on the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047981/how-do-you-implement-size-classes-with-a-custom-keyboard) you were solving in that one, work on [the formatting and phrasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014036/how-do-you-put-a-variable-in-the-array-brackets-in-xcode-5) in that other one... You get the idea. Use what you've learned in the past two years here to go back and make your past questions look shiny.

Then wait for folks to notice...

Comment: How can I improve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047981/how-do-you-implement-size-classes-with-a-custom-keyboard and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260787/force-ios-iphone-youtube-embed-player-out-of-fullscreen ? I really need an answer for both of them. Honestly, I was 10 or 11 when I wrote the other questions, and I don't want to be judged by the noob mistakes I made back then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: "the keyboard does not appear correctly" what do you mean by that? Is the layout wrong? Are there pictures of elves where the keys are supposed to be? Is it literally on fire? Same for your other question: try to describe (or show in images! or both!) as much detail on the *problem* you're trying to fix as possible. Then summarize your goal and the problem in the title. Remember, the folks reading these haven't necessarily been struggling with them for hours/days; they don't have the same context you do when writing it.

Comment: Also... The terms of service here prohibit people under the age of 13 from posting anything or having user accounts here. You're not under 13, are you?

Comment: No, I am not. ()

Comment: @Codengine - But those questions are only a year old.