# Would this workaround enable deleting a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, deletion

If I had a question for which the community is showing it does not need it by downvoting it, will the following work to delete it if it has an answer which was accepted and upvoted only by me?

1. Unaccept the only answer.
2. Edit the answer somehow.
3. Unupvote the answer after the edit enabled that.

Comment: "it's worth noting a particular case where deleting questions counts *heavily* toward a question ban: deleting them right after someone posts an answer..." ([How much of an effect do deleted questions have on bans?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287903/839601))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.