# The "why have I been question banned" FAQ isn't very good at effecting a change in behavior

Tags: feature-request, post-ban, welcoming

### The situation

Today I saw another one in the slew and endless torrent of meta questions about "why have I been question banned?". As usual, it was closed as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) FAQ entry.

Standard fare for a Tuesday morning on meta.SO.

Out of curiosity, I decided to check up on it again, as it's been a long time since I've read it. What I found was a little disconcerting.

As I understand it, the purpose and goal of this FAQ entry is to give question banned users the information they need to unban themselves. This post is heavily referenced whenever the topic of a question ban comes up and is viewed by many-a-user who would like their posting privileges back.

I think, to that end, that it doesn't serve its purpose very well.

### The introduction

Right away, it starts off with this:

> Why am I getting this message?
>
> As stated in the about links on every page, Stack Exchange is a
> network of question and answer sites, not help forums. This implies
> that all posts are expected to have value for later visitors, in
> addition to helping the asker. To enforce that, and to prevent help
> vampires from making the answerers turn away from the community,
> low-quality questions and answers are blocked. This includes posts
> from:
>
> - users who can't be bothered to form sentences
> - users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves
> - users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do

Now, this is pretty confrontational. It may be earned (the user did earn their ban after all), but it's likely not going to effect behavior change. This post is making an argument to the user about the expectations this site has of them, referring to "Help Vampires" and "users who can't be bothered to form sentences" or "users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves" or "users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do" can serve to put readers on the defensive "I'm not that bad, surely!" and cause them to fail to consider what we **need** them to understand to get unbanned.

I think these points are all needlessly confrontative.

### Suggested Edits

First off, I think the blip about help vampires is unuseful and not really needed anymore. Any behavior that would fall under "Help Vampire" is covered in another point of the list already - duplicating the meaning in a catchphrase that can come across as insulting is unnecessary

Secondly, I think the bullet points could use reworking to be less dismissive and confrontative.

Something like:

> This includes posts from:
>
> - users who insufficiently describe their question or don't take enough time to properly formulate.
> - users who don't do enough research of their own before asking
> - users who don't provide enough detail for their question to be answerable

Again, the goal of the post (to my understanding) isn't to let the banned user know just how crap they are at asking questions but to effect change in behavior. To that end, it serves better to be friendly but direct rather than dismissive.

### Further ideas

I also think that it might be of use to reorder the structure of the FAQ - helpful tidbits like where to find your deleted posts or over the nature of the question ban should come after the paragraph on how to get out of it.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but can't you edit the FAQ yourself? It is a community wiki.

Comment: @AndréKool It's locked and can't be edited by non-mods.

Comment: Even if I could edit it myself, editing substantial amounts of a FAQ post isn't something I'd just go ahead and _do_ on my own judgement. I think a community consensus or at least support is necessary for such a change.

Comment: The faq post does get a lot of traffic due to duplicate linking, and it was written quite some time ago. It could make sense to review its content.

Comment: @yivi: That's correct. I've edited that along with a couple of other extremely minor changes. (Don't ask me why I felt like making those minor changes today...)

Comment: The banned users have already ignored the rules, policy, tour and warning emails.  The chances of a change in an advice post affecting their behaviour is zer.... minimal.   That said, I would not oppose a chage in the 'tone' of the advice,  It will have next-to-no effect on the banned users, but it might make the site look less unwelcoming, and does not ask for more work from anybody on a reguar basis.  It's a NOP -  if users want it changed, change it.

Comment: I do believe that most of trafic on those know dupe target are from us trying to find it, or verifying if the dupe answer all the question. Not sure many ban user reach this post. But with my broken English reading the introduction made me feel like : "User that don't even know how to read, write, or are just too dumb to Google!". And that was a little agressive.

Comment: "include" doens't imply "limited to"...

Comment: @MartinJames Even if the chances are minimal, shouldn't we at least make an effort? If we think such users are beyond help, why have time-limited question bans at all? We could simply ban them forever, if we thought they can't change anyways.

Comment: I wonder if there was a reason for [the deletion of the "Are deleted posts taken into account too?" heading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/255584/16) - it seems better with the heading.

Comment: It is worth noting that MSE has the same FAQ and uses the same wording: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/158100

Comment: @Dukeling that revision came [out of an edit action by SOCVR](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/64a207b542dff454613d792ca8498f39). In hindsight we had better posted a new revision as an answer on a question like this one. We had earlier complaints: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=41885447#41885447

Comment: Good thing to know that a FAQ doesn't have to adhere to "be nice". Has that ship sailed?

Comment: @Luuklag: The consistency ship has sailed yes :P

Comment: @Polygnome: I think that hits on the core of the problem. Should we make an effort? Probably. Would we have done seven years ago? Probably. Is everyone a bit tired of "making an effort" multiple times a day for people repeatedly showing the same lack of concern for anyone else? Meh, yep. As a result I'm detecting general fatigue around the community (hence the 'welcoming' post, which ironically just made it all worse) and I don't know whether there's a solution for that, or even whether there's a real problem there. The site is experiencing the problems any community does at scale.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think its understandable that community members are exhausted and frustrated... and expecting everyone to always be super-polite in *every* single comment is unrealistic. But in highly-visible, often linked to FAQ entries, I think we should make an effort to be as neutral, non-belittling as possible.

Comment: @Polygnome: For what it's worth I do agree with that. There doesn't seem to be any need for such confrontational language in "official documents", on that I think we can probably _all_ agree.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I personally think being *more* confrontational *before* they start participating can be a good thing, so they can get a more realistic expectation of how their post is likely to be received, which can, counter-intuitively, be more welcoming. Although I don't really see the point of confrontational language after they've been banned.

Comment: @Dukeling: I do think there are arguments to be _firm_ at the outset, but the specific language quoted here seems way OTT. I think someone wrote it while angry/fed up/drunk ^_^

Comment: @Polygnome The main reason that they aren't banned forever (they used to be) is because when they are they're incentivised to just make a new account.

Comment: @Polygnome What Servy says plus, as I commented, I support this or, at least, don't oppose it, because it's a one-off edit and needs no ongoing effort from users, unlike many of the other proposed 'be nice' suggestions:)

Comment: You should also add "Users who are the victim of close voters who don't properly understand the close system, or who willingly abuse the close system." to the list. That seems to be happening more and more nowadays.

Comment: How do you willingly abuse the close system?

Comment: @Polygnome  'Even if the chances are minimal, shouldn't we at least make an effort?' well, not always.  We should not make an effort to fix problem A if it has no effect on problem B and makes C and D worse. We should also not make an effort if that effort is not going to be cost-effective.  In this case, neither of those issues apply since it's a one-off edit that will have low effect all-round.  So, yes, do it:)

Comment: @MartinJames by willingly using a close reason erroneously to close a question you know does not qualify for the given close reason. I have heard this justified as "well the question needs to be closed but none of the reasons fit..." which is a nonsensical statement in and of itself.

Comment: @TinyGiant oh, I see.  OK, well I admit to tossing a coin between 'Unclear' and 'Too broad' myself sometimes, especially with a mega-dupe h/w dump question where finding and linking the dupe would take more time than the OP spent on 'composing', (copypasta). and posting the question.

Comment: What I think you are missing here is that this FAQ is only used as a dupe when we get a question like "Suddenly I was question banned WTF" rather than "How can I improve this question that got me banned?" The latter shows a will to improve and can't easily be dismissed as a duplicate since it is specific.

Answer (score 24):

I agree that the FAQ is not good. But I don't think it's because it's bad at changing behavior. It's bad because it promises something that we are not very well equipped to deliver:

Redemption.

In essence, the FAQ says "do these things and your ban may go away". But that's just not true. How often do people actually reverse their question bans?

Most bad questions won't be reviewed/upvoted without support from MSO. Many of them may have already been Roomba'd. And we as a community are far more focused on dealing with new questions than old ones that were not asked well to begin with. And *rightfully so*.

So even if we manage to change a user's behavior, that behavioral change is unlikely to pay off. Sometimes it does, but I rather suspect that more often than not, it doesn't.

And if it doesn't pay off, then the FAQ isn't useful at changing behavior, since there is no reinforcement. We ask the user to go through and fix their posts, but it's not enough to actually help them.

So I would say that, while improving the FAQ may be good, without supporting infrastructure that allows the user to more effectively gain redemption, the FAQ will be meaningless.

Right now, we're in a half-state. Our FAQ tells people that they can get the ban lifted, but the reality is that they probably can't.

Which I suppose leads to an unpleasant question: do we really *want* to offer people redemption? Or rather, do we want to pay the *costs* of providing a viable path to redemption?

The kind of infrastructure needed to provide a real way to achieve redemption would be onerous. The most effective one is one that we would enjoy the least: informing voters on a question when it has been edited. That would discourage voting on questions at all, just to avoid the noise of someone trying to fix their post.

Other alternatives would be a special banned-user review queue. But do we really want to spend time looking at edits to questions *specifically* from banned users?

Whatever the changes are, it would require further investment of time by us on such users. Is that something we want? Is that something such users *deserve*?

After all, question bans are not easy to get. You have to violate our community standards multiple times. You have to ask several poor questions. On the way to being question banned, users will be informed (as I understand it) that their questions are not of high quality and they should improve things. Yet they persist.

How much time and effort should the community and Stack Overflow themselves spend on such users? And without spending that time and effort, the FAQ is essentially just a fig leaf: the promise of redemption without any substantive follow-through.

Comment: Most people can't get out of a question ban not because they're able to provide high quality content and it doesn't get recognized by anyone, but rather because *they're not able to provide quality content*.  If they could then *they wouldn't have gotten banned in the first place*.  The problem is that most of the people trying to get out of the ban just go around making minor grammar or formatting changes in edits, and not correcting the underlying problems that resulted in their posts being closed/deleted/downvoted.

Comment: But it is worth mentioning that the whole idea of the question ban is that it's very much expected that most people who reach it will stay there.  Redemption is designed to be *possible*, for those rare cases where someone either makes the determined effort to change, or where someone just has a few unusually bad posts before they figure things out, but it's certainly not *expected* that a large percentage of users will get out of the ban (if that were to happen it would be a sign that people were being banned when they shouldn't be, as they're clearly capable users).

Comment: With incorrect closures and abuse of the closure system being rampant nowadays, I don't think we should be so quick to throw away these users without any chance for appeal.

Comment: @TinyGiant: They *had* the chance for appeal. Many, many times in the past. Again, you don't get a ban for a single question; it requires repeated behavior. Also, I don't know anything about incorrect closures or rampant abuse of the system. Do you have any statistics to back that up with?

Comment: @TinyGiant Citation needed.  That's not the sort of statement you can make without backing it up.

Comment: I see how-to questions being closed with the no-mcve or no-repro (that doesn't make sense at all but whatever) etc all the time. This is not a new problem, people have been erroneously closing questions for a long time and if you ask questions repeatedly in tags where these erroneous closers hang out regularly then you're likely to have your question erroneously closed more than once. Hell before I stopped answering questions I found most of the reasonable questions I wanted to answer _in the close vote queue_. A large portion of the reasonable on-topic questions I have answered are closed.

Comment: The main reason I stopped answering questions was because I was seeing reasonable on-topic questions erroneously closed so regularly that it felt like I was performing a sisyphean task in trying to prevent all these closures and get these posts reopened, and that if I continued I would probably spontaneously combust due to the extreme level of frustration that it caused. A great many people use the closure system correctly, but there is also a great many people who use the closure system incorrectly either on purpose or because they just don't know any better.

Comment: @TinyGiant Alright, so let's see some links.  If this is such a common occurrence, you should have no issue providing evidence to that effect.

Comment: @fbueckert sure, go through my most recent answers and count how many of the questions are closed. I can assure you none of them should be. Honestly I'm done trying to fix a problem that no one else wants to even acknowledge exists, I just came here to again point out that everyone is fallible and we need to not assume that every person ever banned was legitimately banned. Every system has false positives and bad apples. Denying the existence of such things does no good and only prevents us from having an honest and real conversation.

Comment: @TinyGiant: "*Denying the existence of such things does no good and only prevents us from having an honest and real conversation.*" I just looked through the 10 most recent answers in your profile. Not one was closed. I'm not going to spend any more time on a problem that you refuse to substantiate. This is not "denial"; it's "you haven't made a case that this is sufficiently common to be a problem.

Comment: Whatever, I just wanted to bring some honesty to the discussion but obviously no one here wants that. Everyone wants to believe that we are all perfect and infallible. I leave you with your denial.

Comment: @TinyGiant: You've brought no honesty to this discussion. You've injected an unsupported accusation into the middle of it. And just because we don't accept your notion that close vote misuse is widespread does not mean we believe that "we are all perfect and infallible". Your hyperbole is not helping your case at all. Really, if you're not going to substantiate your claims, just don't make them. It would save everyone a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @NicolBolas I can't comment on how frequent they are, but wrongful closures are [definitely not unheard of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=why%20was%20question%20closed%20score%3a2).

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic: Nobody's saying that they're unheard of. But it's hardly an epidemic, is it? If it's not a frequent occurrence, then it's *highly* unlikely that mis-closure of questions is the principle cause of someone's question ban. And therefore, mis-closure is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think the overall point is that *mistakes do happen*. Questions are wrongfully closed and could contribute to someones question ban. It only takes two bad questions for a new user to get question banned and if one of those was closed incorrectly that user is given no chance to improve. If possible, Stack Overflow shouldn't be giving up and turning its back on people. We want people contributing to this site. Permanently banning people from doing so should only be an option if it is abundantly clear that they will not improve.

Comment: I wonder, would it be an inappropriate edit to make the word "Redemption" appear as an H1 tag?  Because that's really driving home the point of the issue with the FAQ.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic:  Bans aren't permanent anymore; you can ask (or answer) a question once every six months.  Not ideal, but not *permanent*, either.

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, that would be inappropriate. I *despise* the use of H1 tags (or even bold-face) to emphasize words. If putting it in its own paragraph wasn't sufficient emphasis, nothing will be.

Comment: \*sigh\*  Fine, @NicolBolas.  Have it your way. :(

Comment: It's not very welcoming to make an accusation and refuse to back it up with evidence.  It's also rude to make an accusation and then ask the accused to put in effort to find evidence.  If someone thinks that something is a problem of such significance that action is warranted, they should provide evidence themselves.

Comment: @MartinJames To be fair, only devs would be able to generate statistics about this, because the rest of us can't tell who's been banned. The best we can do is look at complaints about bans on Meta, which would probably be a fairly small sample size.

Comment: While I think this answer raises a valid issue underlying the original question, in either case (redemption/permadeath) no need to be jerks about it, people (including possibly me!) were probably already jerks to them in the process of them asking the questions that got them banned.

Comment: The FAQ explains clearly how to overcome the question ban. You need to change IP address and create a new account. That's what it's saying, either make some edits and have them ignored or just subvert the ban because that's the only viable option.

Comment: @shogged And then promptly have your new account banned as soon as someone finds out.  Subverting the ban doesn't do you any favors; if anything, it shows an unwillingness to learn from your mistakes and do better.  The number of users who actually put in the effort to try to get out of the ban is vanishingly small.  Those who just don't care and try to subvert it are much higher, I bet.

Comment: @fbueckert you missed the point. There is no realistic way to recover from a question ban, so there is nothing to lose by trying to circumvent it. The FAQ should at least be honest about this, if the consensus is that it's the correct system.

Comment: @shogged Considering that those that hit it have had multiple warnings and roadblocks prior to hitting it, it's not the banned users I'm concerned about, at all.  It's those that have to deal with their low quality contributions that I care about.  The entire process is set up to help them do better, so if they persist in ignoring all the warnings, then that's totally on them.  They can get out by displaying the quality they ignored to get into it in the first place: effort.

Answer (score 16):

The purpose of the FAQ is... To answer a set of frequently-asked questions.

I know you already knew that, but please let's be explicit about it. We need the FAQ because these are frequently-asked questions, not because there's a lot of hope of rescuing banned users. After all, most of the information there is [already in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), and the user is given a link directly to it upon encountering the ban - if that didn't help, then neither will the FAQ.

As it happens, I (and several other people on my team) have years of experience doing what you *propose* the FAQ should do: giving authors the information they need to get out of the ban. And here's what I learned doing that:

1. **very, very, very, *very* few people want the information they need to get unbanned.** The vast majority of folks hitting the ban never even ask for it; the rest mostly just want the ban lifted.
2. **Even fewer want to put real work into it**, so if the relevant information happens to be "edit the last 5 questions you posted to where they're clear and findable by others interested in the topics" they probably won't. Even if you give them links to those questions. Even if you write exemplary titles for the questions you're linking to.
3. **Sometimes the ban is legitimately inappropriate.** Not very often, but... Sometimes someone just got unlucky. *Really* unlucky. We've made an awful lot of changes to how bans work over the years, and this has become a vanishingly-rare occurrence... But it's not completely outside the realm of possibility, and in these cases no amount of information is going to help.
4. **There's a secret trick for getting people unbanned, known only to Stack Exchange support staff.** Ha, just kidding; it's known to everyone, it's just too obvious for most folks to believe. The trick is: if you go through their profile and find a couple of half-way decent questions, edit them to be... let's say 90% decent... and then upvote them... The ban will be lifted in most cases. Of course, the real trick there is finding a couple of half-way decent questions.
5. **did I mention how nobody wants to hear about editing their own questions? Nobody wants to hear about editing their own questions. Or actually do it. Much less do it well.** Seriously, it's not even worth discussing fancy review queues or the like; if you come across a q-banned user you want to help, just edit their questions for them and then toss a few votes at 'em. We already have one review queue predicated on author-edits, and [it's mostly a waste of time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355341/reopen-votes-queue-overrun-due-to-poor-approved-edits-rep-farming/355396#355396) - if you want it to happen, do it yourself.

**All that said...** There's no harm in polishing up a FAQ. The answer is currently locked due to excessive comments, but feel free to write up your own version (in a new question or even an answer to this one) and - if folks like what you wrote - flag it for moderator attention; they can edit it into the FAQ or even just temporarily unlock it so that you can do it yourself.

Comment: Some (likely not insignificant) chunk of the people in this situation have had all of their posts deleted, so point 4/5 isn't an option for users who'd like to try and help - since only mods can see deleted posts by a specific user. I suppose that, if they're in that situation, it's unlikely that they'll ever get unbanned and many of them are likely falling into points 1, 2 and 5. Are these users beyond helping, then? They can at least now come to Meta to ask for specific help if they know to link to their questions, though I'm not sure how well such questions are received here.

Comment: "if you go through their profile and find a couple of half-way decent questions, edit them to be... let's say 90% decent... and then upvote them—" ***S E R I A L U P V O T I N G D E T E C T E D***

Comment: [Discussed further here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting/260843#260843) @BoltClock

Comment: Of course. I never said it was either legit or not :P

Comment: This is [a common misconception](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287902/how-much-of-an-effect-do-deleted-questions-have-on-bans/287903#287903), @Catija. Of the 13689 users to encounter a comprehensive ban on Stack Overflow over the past 90 days, only 3677 - about 27% - had even *half* of their questions deleted. And speaking of 27... That's the precise number of users to hit the q-ban with *all* of their questions deleted in the same time period. See the bullet above about really unlucky users...

Comment: @BoltClock Shog is right in that adding edits into the mix makes reversal check much more lenient, I tested that myself a few years ago. I think this way can pass up to 5-6 posts in the row, especially if you interleave votes with edits (as opposed to "batching"). Another trick is to find a post to vote in opposite direction (shouldn't be hard to find DV-worthy post of a q-banned user), if memory serves this way let me do 8 or 9 "serial" upvotes in a day. Speaking of ban, that many votes almost certainly would push the user out of it

Answer (score 12):

I think that editing the qbanned faq is a good idea. I am not quite as concerned about the help vampire bit so much, kind of on the fence there.

What I would like to see changed though is the layout of the qbanned answer on the faq page. A very large chunk of the answer is describing how the user got there. They are probably aware that their questions were not going well, there is no need to break out a list of all possible things they did wrong and then iterate it with the suggestion that they touched on all of them, *even if they did*. It just isn't constructive.

Instead of showing how they got there, it would be more constructive to show where they can go now. There is a lot of guidance for where they can go now, but it is at the bottom of the post, and tl;dr; *definitely* applies here. For users who did not read rules or abide by guidance, it is a little silly to expect them to read all the way to the end of the qban answer.

tl;dr;

Edit the qban answer to show what actions they can take right at the beginning, and leave the part describing what they did to get there at the end.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Most useful info at start, sure:)   Was probably written the other way up because of timeline: User posts bad questions > user gets banned for it > user has to take remedial action.  Action first, reason for it afterwards seems non-intuitive, even if a better plan overall.

Comment: Forcing users to read a whole wall of text is a feature, not a bug.  The question asks how to change behavior of "Users who did not read rules or abide by guidance" -- catering to their bad behavior will not produce the desired change.